# Main app can't reference framework used in React Native Library

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-bridge

I need some advice about building react native library that using framework. I'm trying to build one using [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/bob) library. My react native library contains these files:

```
Sample-Bridging-Header.h
Sample.m
Sample.swift
Sample.xcodeproj/
Utilities/Utility.swift
Utilities/Helper.swift
Test.framework
```

Inside my `Utility.swift` and `Helper.swift`, I import library `Test` and there is no issue there.

However, when I build the sample app which uses the library, it will not build and it gives the error `no such module 'Test'`.

So it looks like if the main application try to use the react native library, and if the library uses a framework, the main application can't reference the framework. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or not.

I built react native library before and it worked for me but I never have to reference any framework.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just figured out how to handle this. I just need to update the podspec to include the framework by using `s.ios.vendored_frameworks = ios/Test.framework`.

Once I did that, I run `pod install` again for my example project. So now it can pull the framework in properly.